# Salary of Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions Fellowships

Tags: funding

Does anyone have information about the standard salary packages for Marie Skłodowska-Curie Action fellowships inside a Initial Training Network (ITN)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I am understanding the ["Work Programme 2014–2015" of the Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions](http://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/data/ref/h2020/wp/2014_2015/main/h2020-wp1415-msca_en.pdf) correct, then the amount of the living allowance is **37,320 Euro for early-stage researchers** and **55,800 Euro for experienced researchers**. This sum is multiplied by a "country correction coefficient" (see the very end of the Work Programme).